# Compare old view model and current view model in Flutter redux

Tags: flutter, flutter-redux

In Flutter-redux, we can use onDidChange and onWillChange to detect changes in store state. But is there a way to detect change in particular properties?

Can I do something like

`if(oldViewModel.changedProperty != viewModel.changedProperty)`

In react-redux, prevProps and currProps can be checked for differences and perform action based on that.

Comment: did this work for you? I am facing the same issue, and I always have the old and new _ViewModel_ with same values

Comment: I also got  the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// As a performance optimization, the Widget can be rebuilt only when the
// [ViewModel] changes. In order for this to work correctly, you must
// implement [==] and [hashCode] for the [ViewModel], and set the [distinct]
// option to true when creating your StoreConnector.

StoreConnector<AppState, AppState>(
              distinct: true,
              converter: (store) => store.state,
              builder: ),
```

Comment: I don't know why, but I am getting  same state in the both viewModels in == overriden method. I didn't get viewModel which has store with old state and ViewModel with store has new state.